# Randomly assign data to clusters within Class Object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

class EM(object):

    # Initialization
    def __init__(self, X, k=2):
       X = np.asarray(X)
       self.data = X.copy()
       # number of clusters
       self.k = k
       # randomly assign data to the clusters
       self.data['label'] = map(lambda x: x + 1, np.random.choice(self.k, len(self.data)))         # gives the error
```

where X is initially a `pd.Dataframe` with shape (19,182, 5). Running the code gives me the following error:

> *IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices*

How can I write a new column to `self.data`. How is this different from adding/writing/working on a data object outside the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.data` is NOT a dataframe anymore, it's a numpy array. You can see this since you've cast X into an array with `np.asarray`. The IndexError happens since you can't assign to it as you would a dataframe.